# Connecting multiple loads to an extension cord

Tags: power, wiring, load

We have a garage at our house and whilst there is electricity going to it, it's basically just one outlet connected to our second fridge/freezer via a 15A extension cord.

I was wondering if it would be okay to plug the refrigerator (not sure what wattage it is), my soldering iron (90W and has a 500mA fuse), one 24 inch monitor and potentially a laptop charger?

Basically i am not allowed to solder inside the home and was hoping to have this as a set up. It's only temporary as i will hopefully move out this year. What can i do to make this a-little safer?

Edit: The Fridge/Freezer is 800 Watts, the soldering iron is 90W, the monitor is 25W, charger 90W and i'd like to connect a usb hub which is 90W also).
So considering my load is approximately 1100W. My extension being able to supply 230V at 15 A = 3450W. Does it mean it's adequate? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say 15A extension cord?  It should be marked with it's wire size so you should add that to your question.  Is it 12 guage?  What length is it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the nameplates of all the loads in question -- they should list current.  Add up the currents -- if it's less than 15A, then as far as the circuit goes, you're OK.  The more that it's less than 15A, the more OK you are.

At least in the US, extension cords can be rated for less than the current of the outlet they're plugged into.  This can cause problems.

The safe thing to do is to check the extension cord & see if it's rated (in the US, if it's new, there'll be a tag), then make sure you're not pulling more than it's rated for.  Better yet would be to run a second extension cord from that outlet to power your bench.  Extension cords cost a lot less than houses.

I'm the sort who regularly concerns my family and friends with my safety practices, so if I were at less than 15A of the circuit but suspect the extension cord of being on the edge of suitability, I'd go ahead and use it.  But I'd plug everything in and check the extension cord for heating (just hold it in your hand, or coil up some of it tight and hold *that* in your hand).  I'd also inspect the thing for wear.

Comment: I found current values for the various loads except the Fridge/Freezer which is my main concern... So i assume i just do 900W/230V = 3.9A.
4A Fridge/Freezer
500mA soldering iron
240mA lamp
1.8A.     Monitor
1.5A Hub

So that is roughly 8A

Comment: You're probably safe.  Motors consume more current than their power rating would imply (do a search on "reactive power" and "power factor"), but you're enough below 15A that you're probably OK.  Check that cord for overheating even so!